# How to solve "rake aborted! uninitialized constant {My App Name}"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

During a "cap deploy" i end up with the following error messages:

```
  * executing `deploy:migrate'
  * executing "cd /home/{username}/rails1/releases/20120221084010 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["ny.railshoster.de"]
    [ny.railshoster.de] executing command
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] /home/{username}/rails1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.9/lib/ffi/platform.rb:27: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] uninitialized constant {My App Name}
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] 
 ** [out :: ny.railshoster.de] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 1990ms
```

Although i have no idea what went wrong, it doesn't look like a dramatic problem to me. Is there an easy way to solve this? On the server, which is the production environment, a mysql database is used. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: The {} are variable or real value ?

Comment: No, those are just variables, they stand for any name possible for either my username and my app name.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but it looks like `ffi` is to blame. Try upgrading it to the last version (1.0.11 I think) ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I updated ffi to 1.0.11, but sadly the error keeps coming.